# Azure AD B2C logout from all apps

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I've setup 2 saml apps for wordpress and Jira with Azure AD. I'm asked to setup the apps to follow this flow:
1. User signs out from WordPress site
2. User gets logged out of Azure AD
3. Destroy session for all other applications associated with single sign on with active user session(in our case it may be JIRA and other applications).

I have achieved first two steps but struggling with the 3rd one. Azure technical support team says that they provide the feature to destroy sessions of all applications on log out but I can't find any documentation on how to set it up.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To reach destrorying sessions ,you may need session Management. See more details in this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-threat-modeling-tool-session-management

Comment: Is this for Azure AD or Azure AD B2C?

Comment: If Azure AD, have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-out-protocol-reference

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy user’s session of all application, you may need use **Session management**. It imply proper logout **using ADAL methods**. If the application relies on access token issued by Azure AD, the logout event handler should call.

**Example (C#)**

```cs
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
```

It should also **destroy user's session by calling Session.Abandon() method.** Following method shows secure implementation of user logout:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void LogOff()
{
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority + TenantId, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
    authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", string.Empty));
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

See more details about Seesion Management in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-threat-modeling-tool-session-management#logout-adal).

See more details about ADAL in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).